# Which of the major airliners are bleedless?

Tags: commercial-aviation, bleed-air

Bleed air is compressed air taken from a jet engine, and is mainly used to provide pressure for the aircraft cabin.

Fume and smoke events, due to contaminated bleed air, are regularly reported on AVherald.com, including [a 2015 event](https://avherald.com/h?article=4b6eb830) where both pilots were taken ill and the captain later died.

Most airliners in service today use bleed air, a noticable exception is the Boeing 787.

Which other airliners use [bleedless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleed_air#Bleedless_aircraft) systems to provide cabin air?  I'm looking for a list of aircraft models not just the Boeing 787.

Comment: The 787. And a number of combat aircraft.

Comment: @sophit  It only mentions the 787.  I'd like to know if bleedless air is used by any of the Embraer, ATRs, CRJs, Comac, Tupolevs etc. etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very unlikely to find bleedless ECS and Anti-ice on other airliner designs simply because doing it on the 787 required a massive effort to create the electrical support system to make it work, and it's safe to say there aren't any other takers.

Massive generators with the capacity to supply a town, to provide electric anti-ice and cabin heating, and to drive pressurization compressors. And to back that up, Boeing was forced to use Lithium Ion batteries to provide reserve electrical capacity that could not be met with NiCads. This was all a very radical system.

Nobody else has done this on a Western Civilian airliner that I'm aware of and probably never will after the L-ion battery fire fiasco that grounded the 787 fleet and prompted an [AD to require L-ion fireproof enclosures](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2013/04/26/2013-09990/airworthiness-directives-the-boeing-company-airplanes).